# How does the implementation of this Rust trait work in layman terms?

Tags: rust, traits

I wanted to define a trait for a generic type such that its `Add` operation between two referenced values produces a value of the same type.

The solution that works is as follows:

```rust
trait MyTrait<T>: Add<Output = T> + Sized + Clone {}

impl<'a, T: 'a> MyTrait<T> for &'a T where &'a T: Add<Output = T>{}

impl MyTrait<MyStruct> for MyStruct {}

fn some_op<T>(a: &T, b: &T, c: &T) -> T
where
    for<'a> &'a T: MyTrait<T>,
{
    &(a + b) + c
}
// References to MyStruct can be used as inputs to `some_op`
```

What is the second line of this code doing? It seems to reimplementing the same trait for a references to the same generic type, but I don't understand how it does it.

---

If this is considered too trivial for those commenting, suppose I want to define a trait that not only includes addition of values and addition of references, but cross types as well. I.e how do I convert the follow code to use a trait definition as per the above:

```rust
fn some_op<T>(a: &T, b:T, c:&T) -> T 
where
             T: Add<T, Output = T> + Add<&T, Output=T>
for <'a> &'a T: Add<T, Output = T> + Add<&'a T, Output = T>
{
    (a + b) + c
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "how it does it" you implement a trait by writing a `impl Trait for Type {}` block for it. That's lines 3 and 5.

Comment: “When a reference to `T` is `Add<Output = T>`, then make it implement `MyTrait<T>` as well”.

Comment: Because the same `T` is used in the definition of the trait but in the 2nd line both references and the original generic type are used, which is conflicting and confusing. I have rephrased the question. If you know the answer please post your knowledge.

Comment: @BallpointBen, OK so this is like implementing a trait on a generic type conditional on that generic satisfying some other conditions. A trait itself is generally considered as some conditional requirements for a type input so this is kind of a second level of abstraction. Why is not possible to specific this condition directly in the trait declaration itself?

Comment: Your new example can't be expressed as a single trait bound, because the `Self` type is different in both clauses.

Comment: OK so if I want to write multiple functions with multiple mathematical operations all with generic types with cross operations, I have to explicitly add every single Add, Sub, Mul etc, trait bound 4x, and I can't do it with a unified trait?

Comment: Yes you can, you just can't bind different types with the same bound i.e. `T: Add` and `&T: Add` have to be distinct because `T` is a different type from `&T`, `T: Add + Sub + Mul + Whatever` can all be combined to `T: YourSuperTrait`. But before you roll your own, maybe you're looking for [`num-traits`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/num_traits/)?